# Video sequences with Flickering

Tags: video, flicker

I am implementing a tool for flicker removal from Video. To test the tool,
I am looking to get some Video Sequences(Any video format - MPEG4,H263,MPEG2,H264,Raw YUV) which have noticable amount of flickering present in them. I searched, but could not find any such videos.

BTW are there known Video post processing tools which allow flicker removal?

Any pointers would help.

thank you.
-AD

Answer (score 2):

If you have a YUV-sequence, it would be quite simple to add artificial flickering at a certain period (50 Hz, 60 Hz or whatever) by either insert a white frame at the period in question or you can fiddle with the chroma-plane making the frame in question lighter.

Test sequences can be found here. [yuv test-sequences](http://trace.eas.asu.edu/yuv/)

BTW. Normally mobile phones have built in flicker removal that works quite well that operates at a multiple of the net frequency. Slow motion video record at a frame rate not an multiple of say 25 or 30 Hz is something that some camera modules fails to compensate for when recording @ say VGA 100 fps.

Here is a python function to get you started that splits a YUV 4:2:0 into frames and stores each frame as a separate file.

```
def split(fname):
    src_yuv = open(fname, 'rb')

    cif = 352*288*1.5   # YUV 4:2:0 change to reflect your input!

    # Get file size in bytes
    src_yuv_size = os.stat(fname)[6]

    nr_files = src_yuv_size / cif

    filecnt = 0
    while True:
        buf = src_yuv.read(cif)          # read qcif number of bytes
        if buf:
            s = "frame" + "%s" % filecnt + ".yuv"
            dst_yuv = open(s, 'wb')
            dst_yuv.write(buf)           # write read data into new file
            print "writing frame", filecnt
            dst_yuv.close()
            filecnt = filecnt + 1
        else:
            break
    src_yuv.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I have to add a flicker at Frq. say 100 Hz(twice my mains frequency which is 50Hz), then period of flicker becomes 1/100 = 10 milliseconds(msec). If I have a Raw YUV sequence which I play at say 30 frames per second(fps) or 30 frames per 1000 msec. So technically I should be adding a white frame after every 0.3 frame. But that fractional frame becomes meaningless. So Can I add a white frame after every frame? Or how should it be?